# How to integrate Devise with Parse as datastore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, parse-platform

I really want to integrate Devise and use Parse as the Datastore, is there an easy way to do that?  I read through a few thread and it said I will need to rewrite the ORM adapter for it?  How do I go about doing that?

Comment: I have recently started a backend Rails API application which utilizes parse.com and the login details basically have to pass through my app and go to parse.com; Devise is just a storage mechanism and a man in the middle in this case. You don't need to rewrite the ORM adapter, though; rather override certain Devise controller methods to make sure you use parse.com's facilities. I can post an answer for you when I am done.

Comment: I actually opted for using https://github.com/adelevie/parse_resource.